# Silverlight not working in Firefox 3.6.12

Tags: firefox, silverlight-4.0, windows-xp, silverlight-plugin

We are having some wierd behavior in firefox with silverlight. We have tried everything and I am hoping for some more ideas. Below is the behavior

1. Install firefox (3.6.12) and silverlight (4.0.50917.0). The versions there are locked and not controlled by us and on all our users machines.
2. Visit our silverlight application (also tried simple application with just a background)
3. Instead of seeing our application, you see "Get Microsoft Silverlight"
   -- (about:plugins reports silverlight 4.0.50917.0 installed and enabled)
4. Visit site in IE, app works
5. Install or uninstall any plug-in (tried Firebug and IETab2)
6. After install, click "Restart" when prompted
7. After FF restarts, silverlight works as expected
8. Close firefox and reopen.
9. Once again, silverlight is broken

Any ideas? We tried the CWDIllegalInDllSearch entry in the registry to no avail. Please help!

Comment: thats odd. Have you verified this on multiple user machines?

Answer (score 7):

I think it is a problem with Firefox that has been fixed with Version 3.6.14. See this [BugReport](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=478823) on Bugzilla. A memory leak in prior versions, cause some problems in the Silverlight detection script of Firefox.

I can only suggest to update Firefox to version 3.6.14. But before i would try it in a local test environment to check if its really a bug in Firefox.

**Update:**
It seems to be a general problem with Firefox 3.6.x, cause some users report the same error as your with higher versions than 3.6.14. See [here](http://support.mozilla.com/de/questions/788686) and [here](http://support.mozilla.com/de/questions/790046).

Comment: Question doesn't question memory usage. Cannot upgrade FF or Silverlight.

Comment: @All: I´ve read the question and the sentence you are pointing. But sometimes customers or users need to update their programms to use software. For me this seems to be a problem with firefox, so i answered the question with my best knowledge and pointed the questioner to this. Don´t know if this is worth downvoting.

Comment: @All: I have to agree with Jehof's comments here.  We all know that sometimes getting a fix means getting the next version.  Seems like either their rule needs to evolve with the times, or they need to live without the app. (I'm guessing they will evolve their rule). +1 for Jehof

Answer (score 6):

The only thing that springs to mind is disabling the plugin-container

- In Firefox address bar type about:config
- Read the warning, choose your preference to always remind you or not and accept
- In the search bar of the config options now type: npctrl
- You should then see the entry: dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.npctrl.dll
- Change the value from true to false (simply double-clicking will change this for you)
- Restart Firefox

**EDIT**

There is another workaround which is to disable then re-enable silverlight plugin.  Rather than re-isntalling.